# Terraform > The specified key does not exist

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

Running terraform plan is complaining that there's no S3 key in my bucket. Note: this key does not exist however I'm pretty sure Terraform is supposed to create this if it doesn't. The log is:

```
[DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Key>my-key</Key>
```

and the Terraform config is:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "<bucket>"
    key = "my-key"
    region = "eu-west-2"
    acl        = "private"
    kms_key_id = "<key>"    
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: aws credentials/cli set to the same region? The ENV vars will override the SDK vars.

Comment: That's just a debug line in the log, are you actually getting an error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `terraform init` before `terraform plan` to initialise the backend you have configured.

Answer (score 0):

At least in recent versions of Terraform (I'm using 0.11.13) the S3 backend *is* automatically created if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 0):

I spent several hrs on this only to find out remote state file will only be created after `terraform apply` (of course after `terraform init` && `terraform plan`).

```
$ terraform version
Terraform v1.0.4
```